# Subscribe to SENS events from plain C

Tags: c, windows, windows-services, com+

I want to subscribe to some specific SENS events from a Windows service written in C. More concretely, I want to be notified when the user logs into the desktop. Yes, migrating to C# or C++ would be an option (I've seen lots of code examples out there in C#), but I'd rather avoid it, if I can, since it's a pretty large code base.

I didn't know anything about COM or COM+ (other than it existed ;D), so doing some exhaustive research, I started by initializing COM and instantiating `ISensLogon` (well, I *think* I'm doing that). Unfortunately, the call to `CoCreateInstance` keeps on returning `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`.

I'm not asking for the solution right out of the box, I'll be happy if you could provide me some pointers from which I can continue my research. As I said, there are plenty of examples in C#, but not so many in C.

This is the code I used. Simple enough.

```
HRESULT result;
ISensLogon *isens;

printf("Initializing COM... ");
result = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (result != S_OK)
{
    if (result == S_FALSE)
        printf("SKIPPED\n");
    else
    {
        printf("FAILED\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
printf("OK\n");

printf("Creating SENS logon object... ");
result = CoCreateInstance(
    &CLSID_SENS,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    &IID_ISensLogon,
    (LPVOID *)&isens);
if (result != S_OK)
{
    printf("FAILED\n");
    exit(1);
}
printf("OK.\n");
```

The reason I want to use SENS is because I've found the event `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` to be unreliable - it just doesn't always trigger. And I've read about SENS to perform much better.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something. The sample code is not from the service (I can't put printfs on services), but from a tiny sample application I wrote to test SENS. I'm assuming that if it works from the application, it'll work from the service.